# What are the limitations of Octave compared to Python for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, octave

Is Octave good to learn for Machine Learning?
Or Python and other libraries would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to do.

Octave is excellent for fast prototyping and learning. The language is simple and you can focus on grasping the concepts of ML. On the other side, Python is very powerful and has unparalleled stack of libraries and frameworks that give you the ability to dive into machine learning on the level that you are comfortable with. And it's also a simple language in which you can get comfortable pretty fast.

If you just want to play with machine learning a little, I would recommend Octave as it's simple and straightforward. In all other cases, I would recommend Python as it's a powerful language for building complete systems and has a large community which can help you with any problem you could possibly encounter.